# java　filterプログラム追加での文字化け対応について

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

こんにちは。

先日、本番運用しているシステムにて、システム修正したところ、全角の文字が文字化けを起こす、という障害となりました。
前日行った修正としては、log4jのログにセッション情報と利用者IDを出力するようにfilterプログラムを追加しています。

【環境】
OS：CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
tomcat:6.0.39
apache:2.2.21
java:1.7.0_45

【filterプログラム】

```
package util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.log4j.NDC;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public final class NdcFilter implements Filter  {


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NdcFilter.class);
    private FilterConfig filterConfig = null;

    public void destroy() {
        this.filterConfig = null;
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (filterConfig == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

            HttpSession session = req.getSession();

            //if (session== null) {

               Enumeration e = req.getParameterNames();

               while(e.hasMoreElements()) {
                        String key = (String)e.nextElement();

                        //logger.debug(key + "：" + req.getParameter(key));

                        if ( (key.equals("loginId")) || (key.equals("U"))){

                            session.setAttribute("loginId_log4j", req.getParameter(key));
                            logger.debug((String)session.getAttribute("loginId_log4j"));
                            break;
                        }

              }
            //}
            NDC.push(req.getSession().getId() + " " + (String)session.getAttribute("loginId_log4j"));

            try {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } finally {
                NDC.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }


}
```

【web.xml】（抜粋）

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.seasar.extension.filter.EncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>Windows-31J</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>NDCfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>util.NdcFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>NDCfilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingfilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

文字化けの原因はおそらく「encodingfilter」の前に「NDCfilter」を設定したことで、すべてのプログラムの動作がデフォルトのエンコードとなってしまったものと考えています。
（実際に、web.xmlのfilterの順番を逆にしたら文字化けは発生しませんでした。）

そこで、いくつか質問があります。
①文字化けの原因は、私の考える通りであっていますでしょうか？
②デフォルトのエンコードは、そもそもどのように決められるのでしょうか？

①については、皆様のご意見を、②については、手掛かりとなる情報ソースなどあればご紹介いただくと幸いです。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

①あっています。
Filterはweb.xmlに定義した順に呼び出されます。「encodingfilter」の前に「NDCfilter」を設定すると、encodingfilterにてエンコーディングを設定するより前にNDCfilterにてパラメータの値を取り出してしまうため、デフォルトのエンコーディングを使用してしまい文字化けするという結果となります。

②デフォルトのエンコーディングは、TomcatではGETの場合「US-ASCII」、POSTの場合「ISO-8859-1」です。GETはサーブレットの仕様には定義されておらず、Tomcatなど各サーブレットコンテナの実装に委ねられています。POSTはサーブレットの仕様に定義されており、リクエストボディのエンコーディングは「ISO-8859-1」です。

> Default encoding for GET
>    （中略）The character set is defined to be US-ASCII
>
> Default Encoding for POST
>   ISO-8859-1 is defined as the default character set for HTTP request and response bodies
>   http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

最新のサーブレットである3.1の仕様書にも以下のような記述があります。

> 3.11 Request data encoding
>   The default encoding of a request the container uses to create the
>   request reader and parse POST data must be “ISO-8859-1” if none has been specified by the client request. 
>   http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html

なお、US-ASCIIとISO-8859-1はほぼ互換があるため、US-ASCIIはISO-8859-1として考えても問題ありません。

Comment: ありがとうございました。確かに文字化けした文字をみると、POST形式の「ISO-8859-1」となっていました。（かつ、変換できなかった文字は？になっていました。）