# java　filterプログラム追加について

Tags: java, tomcat

こんにちは。

先日本番運用中のシステムにて障害を起こした者です。
※障害の内容については、
[java　filterプログラム追加での文字化け対応について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/13098/java-filter%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%8C%96%E3%81%91%E5%AF%BE%E5%BF%9C%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)
を参照ください。

対応策として、filter-mappingについて再配置する必要があるのですが、実際、どこに配置すべきか分からずに困っているところです。

【環境】
OS：CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
tomcat:6.0.39
apache:2.2.21
java:1.7.0_45

【現在のfilter-mapping】

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.seasar.extension.filter.EncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>Windows-31J</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>requestDumpFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.seasar.extension.filter.RequestDumpFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>hotdeployfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.seasar.framework.container.hotdeploy.HotdeployFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>s2filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.seasar.framework.container.filter.S2ContainerFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>routingfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.seasar.struts.filter.RoutingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jspDirectAccess</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingfilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hotdeployfilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>s2filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>NDCfilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>routingfilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>requestDumpFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

【追加したいfilter-mapping】

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>NDCfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>util.NdcFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>NDCfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>util.NdcFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

「encodingfilter」より後ということはわかっているのですが、そもそもそれぞれのフィルターの意味があまりよくわからずに障害を発生させてしまった反省もあり、意味も合わせて知りたいと思っています。

そこで、次の2点について、ご教示いただきたく、よろしくお願いします。
①各fillterについて、どんな役割をもっているか。
②【追加したいfilter-mapping】を追加する位置はどこが適当か。

ご協力よろしくお願いします！

【追記（8/9）】
A-pZ 様、ｺﾒﾝﾄありがとうございます。
filter定義についても追加いたしました。
フレームワークはstrutsを使っています。

もし足りない情報が他にもありましたら、追記しますのでよろしくお願いします。

Comment: フィルター設定は、2つの設定で成り立っております。

filterで動くクラスとエイリアス(ここではweb.xmlでの名前ですね)、
filter-mappingで、エイリアスと詳細な設定を記載します。

filter設定で、実際に動いているクラスがわかりますので、そのクラスなりフレームワークなりの情報があると、もっと正確な情報やアドバイスが得られると思います。

Answer (score 1):

どうやらSAStruts(Seasor2+Struts1)のようですね。

以下、簡単な説明と公式サイト（日本語）のリンクを参考に。簡単な役割とそれぞれのフィルタの紹介があります。

http://sastruts.seasar.org/fileReference.html

なお、公式に書かれているとおり、「必ず上記の順序で定義するようにしてください。」とありますので順番を入れ替えてしまうと正常動作しないようですね。

sastrutsのサイトにて紹介されていないものとしては、

RequestDumpFilter : 要求(Httpリクエスト)の内容を出力するデバッグ用のフィルタです。
http://s2container.seasar.org/2.4/ja/request_dump_filter.html

かんたんですが以上です。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。
社内でテストしたところ、「routingfilter」より後に「NDCfilter」を設定すると動作しないことが分かりました。
ただ、理論的にそれで正しいかどうか、不安がありますので、もし可能でしたら、「routingfilter」より前でも問題なさそうかどうかの追加情報をご提供いただきますと幸いです。